# sending multiple post variable to another javascript file

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have two separate javascipt file and a php file, on the first create.js i send the variables to the get.php file using post, and then i want to send those variables from get.php to the register.js, how can i get those variables in the register.js and use them to the next step?

this is the code from the first js file:

```
    var fs = $('#fname').val();
        var ls = $('#lname').val();
        var name = $('#adduser').val();
        var pass = $('#addpass').val();
        var cpass = $('#conpass').val();


        if (document.forms['form2'].fname.value == "" || document.forms['form2'].lname.value == "" || document.forms['form2'].adduser.value == "" || document.forms['form2'].addpass.value == ""){
            alert("Input the required Filled!");    
        }
        else{
            var vals;
            var request = $.ajax({
                url:"ifexist.php", type:"POST", 
                data:{
                  n:name
                }
            });                 
            request.done(function(data){
                vals = data; //alert(data);
                if (vals == "1"){
                    alert("Username Already Exist!");
                }   
                else
                    if(pass==cpass){

                            var request1 = $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url:"get.php",
                                data:{ fi:fs, la:ls, na:name, pa:pass}                                      
                            });
                            request1.done(function(data){   
                                alert("Not yet!");
                                location.href = 'captcha.html';
                            //  setTimeout(function() {location.href = 'captcha.html';},1500);          
                            });





                    }
                    else    
                        alert("Password did not match!");

            });
        }
```

and this is the second js file:

```
    $.getJSON('get.php', function(data) {

                            // Inside your success callback:

                            var fir = $("#fi").html(data.uf);
                            var las = $("#la").html(data.ul);
                            var nam = ("#na").html(data.un);
                            var pas = $("#pa").html(data.up);

                            alert("Success!");

                                var request = $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url:"adduser.php",
                                    data:{ f:fir, l:las, n:nam, p:pas}                                      
                                });
                                request.done(function(data){    
                                    alert("Success!");
                                    //setTimeout(function() {alert("Success!");},1500);         
                                });

                        });
```

and this is the php file:

```
    <?php

    $uf = $_POST['fi'];
    $ul = $_POST['la'];
    $un = $_POST['na'];
    $up = $_POST['pa'];

    //add to associative array

    $result['fi'] = $uf;
    $result['la'] = $ul;
    $result['na'] = $un;
    $result['pa'] = $up;

    // encode as json and echo
    echo json_encode($result);

    ?>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You should rather specify a `success` callback inside your `$.ajax` function: `$.ajax({success: function (data) {...} })`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that (send request to browser. well technically you can as push service but that's not what you need IMHO and PHP is tricky in dealing with that) .

why don't you communicate directly within JavaScript after your ajax POST call gets completed? I mean, what do you want to send to register.js?? (don't forget that even though they are separate files they can talk to each other as they are all included)

```
       var post_data = { f:fir, l:las, n:nam, p:pas};

        var request = $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url:"get.php",
              data:post_data                                      
         });
         request.done(function(data){    
              alert(data); //will give you objects the -response form the server
              // now do whatver you need to do, cal an fucntion to create.js,  create trigger, etc.

           });
```

Comment: i want to send this variables:                                          
        var fs = $('#fname').val();
        var ls = $('#lname').val();
        var name = $('#adduser').val();
        var pass = $('#addpass').val();
        var cpass = $('#conpass').val();

Comment: Now, put those in a object as this `var post_data = { f:fir, l:las, n:nam, p:pas};` and use it wherever you want to use it in jour javacript. Please see my code snippet and chekc  my comments